# Host a SOAP web service on a server

Tags: web-services, soap, hosting

I have a SOAP web service code (.asmx) created using VS.NET 2008 which I plan to host on a web server. I am unaware and completely new to the term 'hosting' . My question is whether there are any free and limited period web hosting services that offer me to host a .asmx web service having Microsoft SQL Server 2008 as backend. If yes, what should the approach be from my side ? Should I the upload the .asmx code or the entire VS.NET project ? I am working on localhost at present.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This describes how to deploy ASMX web services:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x71sze4(v=VS.90).aspx

You'll need to find a web host that supports IIS and ASP.NET. I'm not aware of any free hosts that support server side scripts and SQL databases. One of the cheapest options that I've used in the past is GoDaddy, which should satisfy all your needs.

You can test locally if you install IIS 7, available through the web platform installer:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Comment: hey thanks a lot !! but do u know any web host that is free and supports IIS and ASP.NET.. Have u ever tried http://www.aspspider.com/ ? Will this do my job ? and what do I have to exactly host , the code or the entire project ?

Comment: I've never used that site. Like I said above, install IIS locally and get it deployed to your local IIS instance (using the first link I gave you). Once you have it deployed locally, you should be able to copy the entire local deployment to the web server (and of course, update all external references - database connection, etc).